# Replacing all match in a String

Tags: jquery, regex

my string contains some variables which is given between @,`eg:-(@name@)`.
Am passing variables values and storing it in an array. I want to replace this values with the variable in actual string.

This is my code

```
actual_string = actual_string.replace(new RegExp('@'+dynamic[i]+"@"),value);
```

This will replace only one value, If i have same variable repeatedly then the above code will replace only the first occurance. Then i tried

```
actual_string = actual_string.replace(new RegExp('/\@'+dynamic[i]+"\@/"),value);
```

But this is not even replacing single variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `flags` parameter of `RegExp`. Use a `g` to make the search global throughout the string. Try this:

```
actual_string = actual_string.replace(new RegExp('@' + dynamic[i] + "@", 'g'), value);
```

Comment: If I were you, I would not stop at this code. What if `dynamic[i]` contains `?`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no possibilities for that and this works fine for me